# Issue With Anchor Tags Not Scrolling Far Enough in Django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, anchor

I have a Django model called "prompt" that has particular properties, and I have linked these prompts to certain paragraphs (paragraph is another model) in the database depending on whether I want to display that prompt with that paragraph. Before I had starting displaying the prompts on the webpage alongside the paragraphs, my anchor tags inside the "sidebar" area worked properly and scrolled to the correct section of the page, but after I added in the prompts from the Django database, the anchor tag "jumping" functionality stopped working properly.

Here is my code:

```
{% extends 'prompt/base.html' %}

{%block title%} Guidebook for Prompting {%endblock%}
{%block content%} Guidebook on Prompting for Language Learning {%endblock%}

{%block sidebar%} 
    <div class="ml-3 mb-16 grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
        <div class="pb-6"> 
            <div class="col-span-1">
                <ul>
                    {% for section in sections %}
                        <li id="section{{section.id}}" class="py-2 px-2 rounded-xl">
                            <a href="{%url 'section:detail' section.id %}" class="section-link">{{section.section_title}}</a>
                                <ul>
                                    {% for paragraph in section.paragraph_set.all %}
                                    <!-- here is the section where the links are-->
                                        <li id="paragraph{{paragraph.id}}" class="ml-3">
                                            <a href="{%url 'section:detail' section.id %}#paragraph{{paragraph.id}}">{{paragraph.paragraph_title}}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    {%endfor%}
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    {%endfor%}  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="space-y-10 mr-24 text-5xl col-span-3" id="section-text-container">
            {{section.section_title}}
            <div class="mt-10 text-lg">
                {{section.section_description}}
            </div>
            {%for paragraph in section.paragraph_set.all%}
                <!-- jump here -->
                <div id="paragraph{{paragraph.id}}" class="mt-10 text-3xl">{{paragraph.paragraph_title}}</div>
                <div class="text-lg">{{paragraph.paragraph_text | safe}}</div>
                {%for prompt in paragraph.prompts.all %}
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-10 space-x-2">
                        <div class="col-span-5 text-sm border border-gray-700 py-4 px-4">
                            <div class="flex justify-center items-center mt-2 py-4 px-8 bg-sky-500 text-lg rounded-xl text-white" style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 25%;"> 
                                Prompt
                            </div>
                            <div class="mt-10 text-base">
                                {{prompt.prompt_text | safe}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-span-5 text-base border border-gray-700 py-4 px-4">
                            <div class="flex justify-center items-center mt-2 py-4 px-8 bg-sky-500 text-lg rounded-xl text-white" style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 45%;"> 
                                ChatGPT Output
                            </div>
                            <div class="mt-10">
                                {{prompt.prompt_output | safe}}
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {%endfor%}
                <div class="text-2xl mt-10">
                    {%for subparagraph in paragraph.subparagraph_set.all %}
                        <div class="mt-10">
                            {{subparagraph.subparagraph_title}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-lg mt-10">
                            {{subparagraph.subparagraph_text}}
                            {%for prompt in subparagraph.prompts.all %}
                                <div class="mt-10 grid grid-cols-10 space-x-2">
                                    <div class="col-span-5 text-sm border border-gray-700 py-4 px-4">
                                        <div class="flex justify-center items-center mt-2 py-4 px-8 bg-sky-500 text-lg rounded-xl text-white" style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 25%;"> 
                                            Prompt
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mt-10 text-base">
                                            {{prompt.prompt_text | safe}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-span-5 text-base border border-gray-700 py-4 px-4">
                                        <div class="flex justify-center items-center mt-2 py-4 px-8 bg-sky-500 text-lg rounded-xl text-white" style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 45%;"> 
                                            ChatGPT Output
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mt-10">
                                            {{prompt.prompt_output | safe}}
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {%endfor%}
                        </div>
                    {%endfor%}
                </div>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </div>
{%endblock%}
{%block script%}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(window.location.hash.length > 0) {
            window.scrollTo(0, $(window.location.hash).offset().top);
        }
    });



</script>

{%endblock%}
```

The place with the sidebar anchor tags that are supposed to move the user to a certain part of the page after they have been clicked are in the "here is the section where the links are" area, and the place where they are supposed to jump is in the "jump here" comment area.

I tried adjusting the anchor tags so that they would jump to the prompt title area if a paragraph had a prompt, but the same issue with scrolling occurred. From other Google searches, it appears this issue is also common if you have a sticky header, and even though I do not have a sticky header, I tried to follow those guidelines but nothing worked as a result. I figured this must be a problem unique to my Django prompt model displaying on the webpage in between each of the paragraphs, so that's why I decided to come here to ask the question.